# Medical terminology for asymmetrically-shaped paired body parts?

Tags: human-anatomy, terminology, anatomy

Some people have different sized feet [[source](https://www.healthyfeetstore.com/different-sized-feet.html)], a limb that is slightly longer than the [contralateral](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contralateral) (*on other side of the body*) limb [[source](https://www.chop.edu/conditions-diseases/limb-length-discrepancy)], or other instances of paired body parts being different sizes.

These *size* differences in paired body parts on the same individual is referred to as [**hemihypertrophy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemihypertrophy) (or hemihyperplasia).

However, **what is the terminology used to describe variation of *shape/form* of paired contralateral body structures?**

- In other words, what is the general term for contralateral asymmetry?

For example, some women's breasts are asymmetrically shaped ("[breast asymmetry](https://www.health.com/celebrities/jennifer-lawrence-uneven-breasts)"), and some people's fingers are different shapes (for example, [unilateral brachydactyly type D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachydactyly_type_D)).

[image]

<sup>Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachydactyly_type_D#/media/File:Brachydaktylie_Typ_D_einseitig.jpg)</sup>

I assume a term other than "asymmetry" is used, but I have not come across any such generalized terminology.